# How to sava a many-to-many association

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm trying to save a attribute with a many-to-many association in an entity:

```
public static void addPost(Conversation conversation, Post post) {
    conversation.posts.add(post);
    conversation.saveManyToManyAssociations("posts");
}
```

The entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Conversation extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
```

I can load the data but not save a post object after adding to the list. I get this error:

```
[error] Test common.conversation.ConversationModelTest.addPost failed: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_2A ON PUBLIC.CONVERSATION_POST(CONVERSATION_ID, POST_ID)"; SQL statement:
[error] insert into conversation_post (conversation_id, post_id) values (?, ?) [23505-168]
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.ExeUpdateSql.execute(ExeUpdateSql.java:76)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeSqlUpdate(DefaultPersistExecute.java:125)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestUpdateSql.executeNow(PersistRequestUpdateSql.java:44)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequest.executeStatement(PersistRequest.java:74)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestUpdateSql.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestUpdateSql.java:49)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.executeSqlUpdate(DefaultPersister.java:147)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveAssocManyIntersection(DefaultPersister.java:1051)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveManyToManyAssociations(DefaultPersister.java:945)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.saveManyToManyAssociations(DefaultServer.java:1734)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.saveManyToManyAssociations(DefaultServer.java:1721)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.saveManyToManyAssociations(Ebean.java:617)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.Model.saveManyToManyAssociations(Model.java:107)
[error]     at models.Conversation.addPost(Conversation.java:80)
[error]     at common.conversation.ConversationModelTest.addPost(ConversationModelTest.java:80)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_2A ON PUBLIC.CONVERSATION_POST(CONVERSATION_ID, POST_ID)"; SQL statement:
[error] insert into conversation_post (conversation_id, post_id) values (?, ?) [23505-168]
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
[error]     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
[error]     at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:81)
[error]     at org.h2.index.TreeIndex.add(TreeIndex.java:62)
[error]     at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:121)
[error]     at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:124)
[error]     at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:84)
[error]     at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)
[error]     at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:156)
[error]     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:142)
[error]     at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementHandle.java:203)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.ExeUpdateSql.execute(ExeUpdateSql.java:68)
[error]     ... 46 more
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you shure you don't try to add a relation that already exists? In typical scenario that should not be a problem, as you will probably add only totally new posts, however maybe for tests you are trying to add some fixed set?

AFAIK `saveManyToManyAssociations` tries to save whole set of relations as it is, so you need to check if `conversation.posts` doesn't contain the `post` you want to add, and skip the adding if it does.

Comment: Many thanks! Don't need to call explicitly `conversation.saveManyToManyAssociations("posts")`. It looks like it's done magically behinde implicitly.

Comment: Sorry it looks, that's improvement in 2.1 (I refered to 2.0.x), however that's even better :)

Comment: Hmm, it works in the tests but in the running application I need to call `conversation.update()`